# access BlocProvider.of<Bloc>(context) in dispose method

Tags: flutter, dart, dispose, bloc

does anyone have any idea of how I can do this?

My code:

```
  @override
  void dispose() {
    final FiltersBloc filtersBloc = 
       BlocProvider.of<FiltersBloc>(context);
    super.dispose();
  }
```

error is:

```
flutter:         BlocProvider.of() called with a context that does not contain a Bloc of type FiltersBloc.
flutter:         No ancestor could be found starting from the context that was passed to
flutter: BlocProvider.of<FiltersBloc>().
flutter:
flutter:         This can happen if:
flutter:         1. The context you used comes from a widget above the BlocProvider.
flutter:         2. You used MultiBlocProvider and didn't explicity provide the BlocProvider types.
flutter:
flutter:         Good: BlocProvider<FiltersBloc>(builder: (context) => FiltersBloc())
flutter:         Bad: BlocProvider(builder: (context) => FiltersBloc()).
flutter:
flutter:         The context used was: FiltersDrawer(dirty, state: _FiltersDrawerState#86e8a)
```

Also, if I follow the error code and use `final filtersBloc = BlocProvider<FiltersBloc>(builder: (context) => FiltersBloc())` instead, I cannot call `filtersBloc.dispatch()` anymore.

I know for initState, we can just `didChangeDependencies` instead. But I cannot find an equivalent for dispose.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: hello wei. why would you need to get the Bloc inside dispose? do you want to dispose the Bloc object here?

Comment: No, I want to dispatch an event to my bloc when dispose of the widget

Comment: how about declare the ```final FiltersBloc filtersBloc = 
       BlocProvider.of<FiltersBloc>(context);``` in a parent widget then pass it as a parameter so that on dispose, you can use ```widget.filtersBloc.dispatch();```

Comment: Thanks,  i got my answer from here: https://github.com/felangel/bloc/issues/588. It's basically what you said. Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

BlockProvider needs context to be initialized. You may initialize it on the screen's `Widget build()`

```
late FiltersBloc filtersBloc;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context){
  filtersBloc = BlocProvider.of<FiltersBloc>(context);
  return ...
}
```

...then call the desired method on `dispose()`

```dart
@override
void dispose() {
  filtersBloc.dispatch();
  super.dispose();
}
```

Comment: You should point out that `late` is only for projects which are `null safety`.

Comment: this answer is not correct, `didChangeDependencies` should be used instead of `build` method

Answer (score 0):

A small more detailed approach:

**sound null safety**, you can use  @Omatt answer.

**unsound null safety**, you can use the following approach:

Declare a static variable inside the class and assign it inside **init** or **build** as follows:

```dart
class MyAwesomeWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyAwesomeWidget({
    Key key,
  });

  @override
  _MyAwesomeWidgetState createState() => _MyAwesomeWidgetState();
}

class _MyAwesomeWidgetState extends State<MyAwesomeWidget> {
  FiltersBloc filtersBloc;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    new Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
      filterBloc = BlocProvider.of<FiltersBloc>(context);
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    filterBloc.myFunction();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```